# Ria Services not populating complex properties on the client side

Tags: c#, nhibernate, ria

I am trying to use NHibernate with RIA Services. Currently I have two entities:

```
public class Person{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id {get; set;}
    [Include]
    [Association("CurrentEmployer", "CurrentEmployerId", "Id", IsForeignKey = true)]
    public virtual Employer CurrentEmployer { get;set;}
    public virtual int? CurrentEmployerId {get;set;}
}
public class Employer{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual string Name {get;set;}
}
```

When I get a person entity through Ria on the client side the `CurrentEmployerId` is set but the `CurrentEmployer` is still null. On the server side, both the `CurrentEmployerId` and the `CurrentEmployer` are properly populated. Both the `Employer` entity and the `Person` entity are exposed in the same Domain Service.

How do I get the `CurrentEmployer` to be populated on the client side when I get a person? Am I missing an attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered why the `CurrentEmployer` was null. I detached the `Person` from the `DomainContext`

```
_domainContext.People.Detach(foundPerson);
```

before I accessed the `CurrentEmployer` property.